# Weakly prime ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, proof-explanation

In D. D. Anderson and Eric Smith, *Weakly prime ideals*, 2003. There is a theorem
"Let $P$ be a weakly prime ideal of $R$. If $P$ is not prime, then $P^2=0$"

In that proof, i don't understand that if $a+p_0\in P$ or $b+q_0 \in P$, then $a \in P$ or $b \in P$. How it can be? (at the end of picture).

Thank you

here the picture of theorem and the proof
[theorem of D. D. Anderson](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddJLF.png)

Comment: What is a weakly prime ideal?

Comment: a proper ideal $P$ of $R$ to be weakly prime ideal if $0 \neq ab \in P$ implies $a \in P$ or $b \in P$. 

Here, $R$ is commutative ring with identity

Comment: Let $I$ be an ideal. If $x+y\in I$ and $y\in I$, then we must have that $x\in I$.

Comment: thank you. 

i've been trying  to proof that, but i can't yet. 
can i get some clue to proof this?

thank you

Comment: Recall that $a-b\in I\iff a+I=b+I$. Since $x\in I$, we have $x+I=0+I$. Since $x+y\in I$, we have $-y+I=x+I=0+I$. Since $0+I=-y+I$, we have $y=0+y\in I$.

Comment: Thank you. I understand it.

Comment: I'm sorry if my english is not good, or false. I'm trying to develop it. 

Thank you

Comment: Alternatively: $I$ is an additive subgroup of $R$, hence if $x+y$ and $y$ lie in $I$, so does $x+y-y=x.$

Comment: thank you , i hope i can learn more here